# Can't use burg instead of grub2

Tags: boot, grub2, burg

I'm currently running on Ubuntu gnome 16.04 alongside windows 10 in double boot.
I've just installed Burg, and the 
`sudo burg-emu -d` 
command works just fine. I'm able to choose the theme I want.
But when I restart my computer, the old grub gnu is prompting and I have no clue on how can I display burg instead. I obviously selected all the partitions during the installation.

Does any of you have any idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Windows 10, which means you use UEFI.

Unfortunately, BURG does not support EFI, and probably will never (the project seems to have been abandoned).

If you want an alternative to GRUB that works with UEFI, use Clover or rEFInd.

Comment: Thanks a lot, did not know that. Which one of the two solutions would you recommend ?

Comment: @Manu I've never used rEFInd, but I do enjoy Clover. I'm not completely sure, but Clover might only be installable from Mac OS X.